# MyEclipse disable javascript validation in JSP

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp, myeclipse

Is there a way I can disable js validation in jsp in myeclipse. I have jsp page which has java script code in onclick of a button, something like below and jsp is showing syntax error saying there should be `;` instead on `:` after **javascript** so I want to disable js check in jsp. I know to disable js validation in js file but not from jsp file.

`<button onclick="javascript:var .....some js code">Button</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to MyEclipse->Preferences->MyEclipse->Validation, where you can remove the JSP validators. You can also customise the JSP validator at MyEclipse->Preferences->Validation->JSP. In addition, you can exclude certain resources from validation by right-clicking on the project and selecting MyEclipse->Manage Validation, then excluding folders and/or files.

I hope this helps.

Comment: what I was looking is to skip js validation in jsp not complete jsp itself so is that possible or do I have to skip complete jsp itself?

Comment: Sorry, missed this. Did you sort it out? If not, you can switch off client side Javascript validation, either at the project or workspace level. Right click on the project and go to MyEclipse->Manage Validation and you should see what you need to do this there. Select "Enable project specific settings" to do this at the project level, or click on the Configure Workspace Settings link.